# Remove undesired space above and below text in a cell when adjusting size to fit text

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where when I select a salesman from a dropdown list, the worksheet updates to their sales targets and objectives using vlookups to other sheets.

I am trying to use a macro on the objectives section to make the cell size adjust itself to the amount of text in the cell, which can vary depending on which salesman is selected.

I am using merged cells as I want to retain the cell size in rows above the objectives section.

I'm trying to temporarily unmerge the cells to apply a wrap text and autofit to get the cell to fit the text, then put the merge back on.

When I select different Salesman there is some autofitting. The issue is there is a lot of unnecessary space above and below the text.

```vb
Sub Adjust_Cells_For_Text()

Range("D33:M42").UnMerge
Range("D33:M42").WrapText = True
Range("D33:M42").EntireRow.AutoFit
Range("D33:M42").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("D33:F33").Merge
Range("D34:F34").Merge
Range("D35:F35").Merge
Range("D36:F36").Merge
Range("D37:F37").Merge
Range("D38:F38").Merge
Range("D39:F39").Merge
Range("D40:F40").Merge
Range("D41:F41").Merge
Range("D42:F42").Merge

End Sub
```

Space around text example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Adjust_Cells_For_Text()
        
    With Range("D33:M42")
        .UnMerge
        .WrapText = True
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("D33:D42")
    
    ' Merge cells
    For Each rCell In rng
        rCell.Resize(1, 3).Merge
    Next rCell
    
    ' Autofit
    Rows("33:42").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```